# Screen Scraping Efficiency

Tags: programming-languages, performance, screen-scraping

We are going to be scraping thousands of websites each night to update client data, and we are in the process of deciding which language we would like to use to do the scraping.

We are not locked into any platform or language, and I am simply looking for efficiency.  If I have to learn a new language to make my servers perform well, that is fine.

Which language/platform will provide the highest scraping efficiency per dollar for us?  Really I'm looking for real-world experience with high volume scraping.  It will be about maximizing CPU/Memory/Bandwidth.

Comment: Any modern language on a moderate spec machine would do.

Comment: Well if the only thing you care about is efficiency, you'd go as low level as possible, but there is obviously a trade-off to make here on cost of hardware vs cost of programmer hours.

Comment: That's a good point, no assembly of course. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will be IO bound anyway, the performance of your code won't matter at all (unless you're a really bad programmer..)

Comment: That's a good point.  That being said, which language leans towards quick screen scraping development?  Maybe we should consider development time instead of server time in this scenario, something I hadn't considered before.

Comment: @Mike, It's more about the libraries than the actual language. Every language has DOM libraries. I lean towards C# because that's my main language, but every language has at least one good one! One point though is that C# 4 has some very easy to use parallel operations, allowing you to easily process multiple files at once (`Parallel.For`).

Comment: Well we are mainly a c# / Objective C shop, so I appreciate your opinion on that.  We'll try it out!

Comment: @Mike, then you want to get HTML Agility Pack, the usual .NET DOM library of choice.

Comment: It depends. If you require to run javascript the issue is not only IO bound but CPU bound. HTMLUnit is a very good library but slow. Running things like PhantomJS or your own WebKit browser is the fastest way to work around it, BUT it is CPU bound.

Answer (score 0):

Using a combination of python and beautiful soup it's incredibly easy to write scree-scraping code very quickly. There is a learning curve for beautiful soup, but it's worth it.

Efficiency-wise, I'd say it's just as quick as any other method out there. I've never done thousands of sites at once, but I'd wager that it's definitely up to the task.

Comment: Which could be said regarding just about any other language/platform and the associated HTML parser.

Answer (score 0):

If you know C, a single-stream synchronous link (called the "easy" method) is a short day's work with [**libcURL**](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/). Multiple asynchronous streams (called the "multi" method) is a couple hours more.

Answer (score 0):

For web scraping I use Python with lxml and a few other libraries: http://webscraping.com/blog

I/O is the main bottleneck when crawling - to download data at a good rate you need to use multiple threads.

I cache all downloaded HTML, so memory use is low.

Often after crawling I need to rescrape different features, and CPU becomes important.

Answer (score -1):

With the volume that thousands of sites would require, you may be better off economically by looking at commercial packages.  They eliminate the IO problem, and have tools specifically designed to handle the nuances between every site, as well as post-scraping tools to normalize the data, and scheduling to keep the data current.

Comment: What evidence can you present for this?

Comment: We are currently using a service that does this for us, and our monthly bill will hit about $500,000 soon.  Thus the reason we want to start doing it in-house.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend [Web Scraping Language](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wslang)

compare a simple WSL query:

`GOTO example.com >> EXTRACT {'column1':td[0], 'column2': td[1]} IN table.spad`

with the following example:

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('http://example.com').read())

for row in soup('table', {'class': 'spad'})[0].tbody('tr'):
    tds = row('td')
    print tds[0].string, tds[1].string
```

Comment: WSL is defunct/gone and no archive.org copy exists.